# How to Create a Apple Music User Token outside iOS

Tags: ios, storekit, apple-music

I am trying to let people like tracks, albums or playlists on Apple Music from a webpage.

I understand the manual on this page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/SetUpWebServices.html

Until I hit the part where I should use the `requestUserToken(forDeveloperToken:completionHandler:)` method from SKCloudServiceController in the StoreKit framework, since there is no StoreKit framework available for outside iOS/macOS/tvOS/etc.

How is this token generated? Is there any other way I can generate this Music User Token manually?

I know it is a (very) longshot, but maybe someone figured it out!

Comment: Token can be generated from here: https://www.example-code.com/swift/jwt_ecc_create.asp even it has ES256 encryption but it accepts pem file and apple provide p8 format file. I have searched  a lot but didn't get any solution for conversion from p8 file to pem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the approach within my iOS app.

You can follow this link [generate music token](https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator)

This is basically python script. You can easily create a music developer token from your mac.

Comment: Hey Thanks for adding your answer! I forgot all about this question, but luckily I did find that repo too eventually.

Comment: @Reinier ,@AbdulYasin - this doesn't allow for the generation of user tokens outside of the US though , does it?

Comment: @AbdulYasin Thanks for answering. I'm referring to User tokens not developer tokens. Would it be possible for you to show how this can be done in the answer? I mean, where do you prompt the user to enter his credentials before acquiring their token? Note: I'm not talking about iOS. I'm talking about a web-app.

Comment: @zerohedge You will find the above link much helpful. To generate the user token (a MusicKit private key in a *.p8 file, a 10-digit key identifier in your Apple Developer account and your 10-digit Apple Developer Account Team ID), you can visit Apple member centre. If you have a member account, you can proceed with the generating the stuffs.

Comment: @AbdulYasin I’ve already been there and it’s still unclear to me how to identify for example a Windows user who has Apple Music on his iPhone from a Python web app. Thanks for your help in any case

Comment: This answer is wrong, as it generates a developer token, not a user token.  The dev token is just a stepping stone, as it identifies which client app is asking, the user token allows the client access to the service via a particular account.

Answer (score 5):

The new Apple MusicKit JS library allows you to create Music User Token's from your Developer Token as seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickitjs) outside of iOS. Once you've loaded the Library you can use the `authorize` method to allow a user to authenticate and generate a token.

```
document.addEventListener('musickitloaded', function() {
  // MusicKit global is now defined
  MusicKit.configure({
    developerToken: 'DEVELOPER-TOKEN',
    app: {
      name: 'My Cool Web App',
      build: '1978.4.1'
    }
  });

  let music = MusicKit.getInstance();

  music.authorize().then(musicUserToken => {
    console.log(musicUserToken);
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this token need to be encrypted if I want to save it to my database for each user?

Comment: It returns 'undefined' to me

Comment: I have tried all methods like `'music.musicUserToken'` but still doesn't work for me

Comment: I made a basic example of getting the js sdk setup [here](https://github.com/KoleMyers/apple-musickit-example). Once configured the `music` variable should be available in the console and you can run
`music.authorize().then(musicUserToken => {
  console.log(musicUserToken);
});`
to login. You will need an Apple Music account to login. Hopefully this helps

Comment: @KoleMyers Hi, I am trying to authorize user but after login nothing happens. Empty window displayed.

Comment: @Degard - hmm It looks like it's still working for me. Are you trying the setup in that github project I linked? if so open an issue on the project with your details and I'll try to figure it out.